# Matrix of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory, stl, c++11

Is it considered good practice to put `unique_ptr` in an array? Yes, I know, they have unusual copy semantic, but my idea is this:

I have a tiled-based game field. Each pointer in the array points to some game object. When I assign something new to an array element, the previous object is destroyed and a new one is placed.

Another question -- the same about shared_ptr, because sometimes I will use flyweight pattern.

Comment: unique_ptr : is this intelligent-pointer?

Comment: Man, why you ask me, not google? Yes, It is poiter with ownership semantic.

Comment: What constitutes "good practice"?

Comment: Not-fragility and error-proness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of `unique_ptr`'s biggest *advantages* is that it's safe to use in Standard containers like `std::vector`. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is no anti-pattern, it's perfectly fine and highly recommended.

Comment: Is it safe to put it in `boost::blas::matrix`?

Answer (score 3):

In general yes, this is good practice: in that case, the matrix would be the owner of the objects (which should work well in most cases) and other consumers of the object merely retain raw pointers to the objects, if at all.

This is safe and efficient.

On the other hand, consider whether you need pointers at all. If I understand correctly, the only reason for using pointers here is to be able to store polymorphic objects. Consider whether `boost::variant` may be an alternative here, or some kind of `value_ptr` (which unfortunately isn’t included in the standard library, but easy to implement).

Comment: No value_ptr! No copying! I do not favor `boost::variant`, because it uses rtti. And my object are not copyable.

I really need ptrs, and I am glad, that it is safe.

Comment: @illusionoflife `value_ptr` doesn’t imply copying: you can (and should) handle references, since your matrix manages ownership anyway. And `boost::variant` doesn’t use RTTI. It *does* use type erasure which isn’t always appropriate (say, when you’ve got a well-defined common interface). But other than that, it’s the bee’s knees.

Comment: Well, when I say about rtti, I mean that I do my best to compile my code with `-no-rtti` flag. It discards `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`.

Comment: @illusionoflife: He knows what RTTI is. That doesn't change the fact that Boost.Variant doesn't use RTTI. Also, compiling without RTTI is pointless, unless you are working in an environment where you have very specific ***needs*** that prevent it's use, rather than a belief that RTTI is somehow bad.

Comment: Strange. My bad -- boost/variant compiles with `no-rtti`.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing unusual about the copy semantics of `unique_ptr`; they can be moved but not copied, and hence are entirely suitable for use in a standard container.

You may be thinking of the deprecated `auto_ptr` which, before move semantics were added to the language, tried to emulate them using destructive copy semantics. This made them very difficult to safely use with standard containers.

Whether you should be storing pointers or objects in the container is another question. Generally, it's better to store objects; unless they're very large or otherwise expensive to move, or unless you need to store (pointers to the common base class of) objects of different types.

If you do want to store pointers, and want the container to manage the lifetime of the objects, then `unique_ptr` is the best choice. `shared_ptr` is also suitable, if you want to share ownership with other entities, or if you want to use `weak_ptr` to determine whether the object has been removed from the array.

Answer (score 1):

In general unique_ptr is more performant than shared_ptr because it doesn't do reference counting, however one place must have ownership.  This is risky because if you have:

```
vector<unique_ptr<GameObject>> v;
```

You would take a reference to it with:

```
GameObject* p = v[42].get();
```

and then if position 42 is deleted or replaced, p will be a hanging pointer.

However:

```
vector<shared_ptr<GameObject>> v;

shared_ptr<GameObject> p = v[42];
```

Will keep the underlying object around for p even if v[42] is deleted - but you have the overhead of the reference count update.

My suggestion would be to prefer shared_ptr because its safer, unless performance becomes an issue.

Comment: If my code perform any actions on objects, removed from game board, it is logic error. So I prefer to crash over operation on valid objects with no effect. 

Yes, I know, unfortunately, dangling pointer is not always means crash.

Comment: In that case I would use a weak_ptr to take references to it.  They will automatically change to null pointers if the object is removed from the array.

Comment: (You can't rely on hanging pointers to crash because sometimes they don't.)